# Is Android Wear device used Bluetooth to connect to Android Phone device over the air?

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, wear-os

Followed [`Android Wear GUIDE`](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html).

People noted this :

`The Android Wear Preview app is compatible with Android 4.3 and higher and is not available for the Android emulator.`

This thing may be indicated that it will use Bluetooth Low Energy - BLE, to establish connection between Android Wear device - Wrist Watch, and Android mobile devices since `BLE technology only be available on Android 4.3 or higher, and not available on Android Emulator`. But I am not sure.

Currently I know this to connect Android Wear Emulator with Android Phone device :

`Connect your device to your development machine over USB`.

But I wonder that when Wrist Watch device with real Android Wear SDK was released,

It will be used what's thing to connect to Android Mobile device?

Please tell me,

Thanks,

*p/s : If I am right, it also means the Android Mobile devices can connect to Wrist Watch will be limited since not most of Android Mobile devices always support BLE technology.*

Comment: I guess yes...n most probably they use BLE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: No-one knows for sure.

Long story long: Your observations point to BLE, and looking at the emulator we can also find pieces of information pointing to a bluetooth-based connection.

But until Google releases more information on how things are going to be, we cannot say anything for sure yet.